# Generating a bounding box around a fragmented silhouette in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, bounding-box

Hello I am working with matlab. I am trying to generate a bounding box around a silhouette. The problem here is that the silhouette is fragmented
as shown here

[image]

The code i tried is

```
BW=bwconncomp(image);
STATS = regionprops(BW, 'FilledArea','BoundingBox');
```

which gives me a bounding box around a part of the silhouette. I cannot use `dilate` which is the preferred morphological operation in this case as it connects the silhouette with neighboring fragments.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Is this the original image? Or a few steps down the processing line? Because there might be a better way to do the segmentation that wpuld make this easier. At the least can you circle which part of the binary mask is the 'silhouette' since it is not immediately apparent.

Comment: The region on the right is the person. The silhouette is obtained after a little processioning. The initial silhouette was one complete blob connecting all the fragments.

Comment: Can you post the original image with no processing?

Comment: @user2307268 so did you try the suggestion below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something to get you going with the image you posted. I used a line structuring element with an angle to dilate the image and amplify the signal from the small white chunks at the left of the silhouette. Then using `regionprops` its easier to identify objects individually and select the object with the largest area (i.e. the silhouette), calculated with the property `FilledArea`, and report back the bounding box on the original image. It might not be perfect but it's a start and it seems to give a pretty decent result.

Here is the code:

```
clear
clc
close all

BW = im2bw(imread('Silhouette.png'));
BW = imclearborder(BW);

%// Dilate with a line structuring element oriented at about 60 degrees to
%// amplify the elements at an angle that you don't want.
se = strel('line',5,60);        
dilateddBW = imdilate(BW,se);

figure;
imshow(dilateddBW)
```

The dilated image looks like this:

[image]

Calling `regionprops` and displaying the output:

```
%// Get the region properties and select that with the largest area.
S = regionprops(dilateddBW,'BoundingBox','FilledArea','PixelIdxList');

boundingboxes = cat(1, S.BoundingBox);
FilledAreas = cat(1,S.FilledArea);

[~,MaxAreaIndex] = max(FilledAreas);

%// Get linear indices of the corresponding silhouette to display along
%// with its bounding box.
MaxIndices = S(MaxAreaIndex).PixelIdxList;

%// Create empty image to put the silhouette + box
NewIm = false(size(dilateddBW));

NewIm(MaxIndices) = 1;

figure;

imshow(BW)
rectangle('Position',boundingboxes(MaxAreaIndex,:),'EdgeColor','r')
```

Output:

[image]

Hope that helps somehow!

Comment: it seems you're into Image Processing - could you assist us open this dedicated group: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66531/computer-vision/72084 Just vote to questions with less than 10 up votes. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Since you have an array of vectors containing indice of pixels(bwconncomp() returns a struct which have a member named PixelIdxList), you can create a rectangle by finding pixels with min x, min y, max x, max y.

Here is a good example: [2D Minimal Bounding Box](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31126-2d-minimal-bounding-box/content//minBoundingBox.m)

Comment: I didn't downvote but this is hardly an answer; can you elaborate or maybe provide some code that could be useful to the OP?

Comment: @sithereal, it seems you're into Image Processing - could you assist us open this dedicated group: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66531/computer-vision/72084 Just vote to questions with less than 10 up votes. Thanks.